# React Native Transforms for move view on layout

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-animatable

I'm developing an app.
This app has a HomeScreen where 6 icons are displayed. When I press on an icon react navigator navigate to a new screen.
When I press the icon, before transition, it has to happen an animation.
I don't want to use Transitioner for previous problems.
This is my screen when I press on an icon I want that the icon opacity goes to 0 and it moves at left-top of the screen (immediately below of header).
But I am wanting it to support all device and I can't calculate the distance, the translation, the initial position etc for everyone, I have designed it with flexbox, not with absolute position.

I have tried to starting from position 0 the animated.view and arriving at the calculated position based on screen, but I could no longer manage the code

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  //tester.retrieveDataById()
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: [
        { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
        { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) }
      ]
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {..}


  _onPressButton = (info, icon, index) => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.value[1].fadeAnim,
        {
          toValue: index === 1 ? 1 : 0, 
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.ease,

          useNativeDriver: true 
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.value[0].fadeAnim, 
        {
          toValue: index === 0 ? 1 : 0, 
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.value[2].fadeAnim, 
        {
          toValue: index === 2 ? 1 : 0, 
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.value[3].fadeAnim, 
        {
          toValue: index === 3 ? 1 : 0, 
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.value[4].fadeAnim, 
        {
          toValue: index === 4 ? 1 : 0, 
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.value[5].fadeAnim, 
        {
          toValue: index === 5 ? 1 : 0, 
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }
      )
    ]).start(() => {
      console.log("dasd");
      this.props.navigation.navigate(info, { icon: icon });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          value: this.state.value.map(
            element => (element.fadeAnim = { fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) })
          ) //restore the state when I come back from navigate
        });
      }, 500);
    });

  };



  // the space in text is need for alignment among them
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "space-around"
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.value[0].fadeAnim }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this._onPressButton("VenetoWelfare", Medal, 0)}
                style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                <Medal
                  width={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  height={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  fill="#7A9DBC"
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginBottom: normalize(4)
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                text {"\n"} text {"\n"} text
              </Text>
            </Animated.View>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.value[1].fadeAnim }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  this._onPressButton("WelfareCollettivo", Collective, 1)
                }
                style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                <Collective
                  width={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  height={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  fill="#7A9DBC"
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginBottom: normalize(4)
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  text {"\n"} text {"\n"}{" "}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>

            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.value[2].fadeAnim }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  this._onPressButton("AssistenzaSanitaria", Care, 2)
                }
                style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                <Care
                  width={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  height={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  fill="#7A9DBC"
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginBottom: normalize(4),
                    transform: [{ translateY: -0 }]
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  text {"\n"} text {"\n"} text
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "space-around"
            }}
          >
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.value[3].fadeAnim }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this._onPressButton("Previdenza", Analysis, 3)}
                style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                <Wallet
                  width={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  height={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  fill="#7A9DBC"
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginBottom: normalize(4)
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  text {"\n"} {""}
                  {"\n"}{" "}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.value[4].fadeAnim }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  this._onPressButton("PrevidenzaComplementare", Wallet, 4)
                }
                style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                <Wallet
                  width={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  height={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  fill="#7A9DBC"
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginBottom: normalize(4)
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  text {"\n"} text {"\n"}{" "}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.value[5].fadeAnim }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  this._onPressButton("WelfareAziendale", Industry, 5)
                }
                style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
              >
                <Industry
                  width={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  height={`${normalize(50)}`}
                  fill="#7A9DBC"
                  style={{
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginBottom: normalize(4)
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                  text {"\n"} text {"\n"}{" "}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: normalize(18),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#7A9DBC"
  }
});
```

I have already obtained the opacity as you can see from the code above.
I have no idea how to do the translations since the icons are inserted in a specific view.

Comment: Try to use dimensions to get width and height of the screen. Then you can animate with values from dimension. Example: const SW = Dimensions.get('window').width/100; then use SW variable in your animations as value then it will be much more responsive

Comment: each icon must move to a different coordinate value (translatex and translate y) because they are positioned in 6 different view boxes. I don't know their initial position. How do I know how to move them?